# codeigniter dom-pdf - No block-level parent found. Not good

Tags: dompdf

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'DOMPDF_Exception' with message 'No block-level parent found. Not good.' system/library/dompdf/include/inline_positioner.cls.php:37

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Remove `<thead>` and `<tbody>` tags 
and remove space between `<html><head>` , `</head><body>` and `</body></html>`

It will works fine.!

Comment: It's Working fine ..!
Thnkx for quick help . :)

Comment: I don't have  the thead and tbody , , its plain simple heading  and i am facing same issue

Comment: Remove extra space between "html" and "body" tag